# Sybase isql won't execute sql file when USE DB GO

Tags: unix, sybase, isql, udeploy

I'm creating this process on uDeploy that uses iSQL to execute sql files. My problem is that I have to set the server and db name in the process.

In the SQL file - we may need to use other db's so it'd have to include USE DBNAME GO in the file.

However, it hasn't been reaching/executing the update statement after the USE statement.

Is there anything in relation to sybase, isql, that doesn't allow this? 
Can you only do one statement from isql?

typical linux cmd being run is

```
sybase.sh; isql -U username -P **** -S servername:port -D dbname -X -i sqlfile.sql
```

SQL file example:

```
USE dbname
go
update table set field = 'date' where field1 ='blahblah' and field2 ='blah'
go
```

edit:

This might be because the DBNAME is being set in the command. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: alright - wrong word, but that doesn't add to the solution. Anyway, its because of hte dbname being set in the command probs, haven't seen anyone trying to change db within this so can't know for sure.

Comment: would help if you updated your example with some sample database names; as is, `dbname` == `dbname`, so both examples should run your query in a database named `dbname` ... assuming your login has access to a database named `dbname`; I'm assuming you're got differently named databases ... in which case I've explained one probable issue (see my answer - below)

Answer (score 1):

Some background:

From the command line:

```
isql -U ... -P ... -D >dbname< -i >script<
```

- will run `>script<` in the database named `>dbname<` (assuming your login has access to the `>dbname<` database; otherwise the script will be run in your login's default database)

In a script:

```
use >dbname<
go
select ...
go
```

- assuming your login has access to database `>dbname<` ...
- will place the session in the database name `>dbname<` and ...
- then run your query
- if you don't have access to the `>dbname<` database then you should get an error message and the follow-on query(s) will be run in your default database

---

Your (probable) issue:

- while the `isql / -D >dbname<` will set the destination database ...
- the `use >dbname<` in the script will take precedence and determine which database you're ultimately placed in prior to running the follow-on query(s)

An example ...

```
$ myquery.sql
use tempdb
go
select count(*) from sysobjects
go

$ isql -S ... -U ... -P ... -i myquery.sql
```

- since no `-D` argument is provided on the `isql` command line, the script will place you in the `tempdb` database prior to running the `select`

Now if we add a `-D` flag ...

```
$ isql -S ... -U ... -P ... -D master -i myquery.sql
```

- while the `isql` command line option `-D master` will initially place your session in the `master` database ...
- the script will override this by then placing you in the `tempdb` database
- net result is the `select` will be run in the `tempdb` database

Comment: what if the isql / -D >dbname< and use >dbname< are the same?

Comment: doesn't matter; `isql/-D` is applied first, then `use` is applied (ie, `use` overrides `isql/-D`)